# Smarty Framework Backend Code Not Updating Website

Tags: php, smarty

I am running  a Smarty Framework based website on my local machine (on a virtual server). When I update some of the backend code, it does not change anything regarding the code that I have changed/added. I also tried adding a `<p>` tag in the front end, but this is not even outputting the tag value. It seems like the code is not being read at all.. I also tried restarting the wamp server, but still nothing happened.

What could be the problem regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your template files are compiled or even you have some cache implemented.

First you should remove content of compiled templates (by default `templates_c` folder) and check if the modification is visible.

If modification is visible, you should check what's the value of Smarty property

```
$smarty->compile_check = true;
```

If it's true as above each time when you change something in your template file Smarty will recompile this template file so you should see modified content. On production however when you in fact don't modify template files you should set it to false (and maybe that's the setting in your case). So you can change it to true but on production it should be rather set to false because of performance.

However as I said even that may not work if you have in your system some cache enabled. In this case you will have to manually clean your cache dir.